# Difference Between in fatal and parse error in php

Tags: php

I am confused about the fatal error and parse error in PHP.

suppose, parse error means syntax error.
i have one exaple about parse error:

```
<?php
echo "red";
echo "Green"
echo "yellow";
?>
```

semicolon missing in line 2 so, is it execute next line or not? **

please explain more about fatal and parse error?

Comment: Parsing is done before the script is executed, so nothing will be run in this case.

Comment: `missing in line 2 so, is it execute next line or not?`...it won't execute any of the lines, before or after.

Comment: so , is it same as fatal error? @ADyson

Comment: No. Fatal error is a runtime error - that won't fail until it reaches the line where it falls over. Other lines before it would be executed. But for a parse error, it means the compiler cannot even make sense of the program properly, so it cannot execute any of it. (Compare it to trying to read a message in a language you cannot understand - you can't read of it it. That's like the parse error. But if it's a language you understand, you read most of it but then have one problem which means you can't carry on with the rest of it - that's like the fatal runtime error.)

Answer (score 0):

Parse errors are caused by:

Unclosed brackets or quotes
Missing or extra semicolons or parentheses
Misspellings

```
<?php
echo "red";
echo "Green"
echo "yellow";
?>
```

Here you are missing semicolon

#### fatal error

Startup fatal error (when the system can’t run the code at installation)
Compile time fatal error (when a programmer tries to use nonexistent data)
Runtime fatal error (happens while the program is running, causing the code to stop working completely)

```
<?php
  
function add($x, $y)
{
    $sum = $x + $y;
    echo "sum = " . $sum;
}
$x = 0;
$y = 20;
add($x, $y);
  
diff($x, $y);
?>
```

Above call diff() function which is not define

For More info please check [PHP Errors](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-types-of-errors/)

Comment: line no 2 missing semicolon so is it show error msg but not stop the execution. OR same as fatal error like semicolon missing show the error and not execute the script future?

Comment: its show error not show you any output Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ';' or ','  it not execute any code line .